# Python fuction does not terminate after exception handling

Tags: python

If I may ask:

My python code is not terminating even after en exception handling routine.

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np

def calculate(num_list):
    try:
        num_array = np.array(num_list)
        num_array = np.reshape(num_array, (3, 3))
        # If the number of elements in num_list
        # is less than 9, np.reshape will return a
        # ValueError

    except ValueError:
        print("List must contain nine numbers.")

    # The problem is that after catching error with  
    # except ValueError:, the function continues 
    # and runs the three lines below.
    # And so, since num_array is not a valid input, I get
    # an axis value error.

    mean_list.append(np.mean(num_array, axis=0).tolist())
    mean_list.append(np.mean(num_array, axis=1).tolist())
    mean_list.append(np.mean(num_array).tolist())
```

I've been able to work around the problem by using:

```
sys.stop() # After the print statement #
```

or by adding an if statement before the mean_list.append codes

```
if len(np.array(num_list)) >= 9:
```

However, I'm sure there's something wrong with my excpetion handling. Would appreciate if someone could explain what I'm missing.

Many thanks. Appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, you caught the exception. Only an *uncaught* exception causes the interpreter to exit. If you don't know how to fix the problem that causes the exception, don't catch it.

Comment: Do you want the `except` clause to exit the program or return from the function? You can do anything you want there.

Comment: Hi. Python, like any other language, has an excellent documentation. The preferred way of learning the basics of a language is to find a book or an online tutorial, and also search for the topics if interests in the documentation. For example https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html . While there are many people willing to help you here, the recommended approach is to learn the basics first. There are plenty of YouTube videos and online courses available. Good luck on your journey.

Answer (score 4):

You only caught the exception to log some information but otherwise want the exception to propagate back to the caller. So just reraise.

```
import numpy as np

def calculate(num_list):
    try:
        num_array = np.array(num_list)
        num_array = np.reshape(num_array, (3, 3))
        # If the number of elements in num_list
        # is less than 9, np.reshape will return a
        # ValueError

    except ValueError:
        print("List must contain nine numbers.")
        raise

        # or return an error (and return True otherwise)
        # return False
        # or convert to a different exception
        # raise MyAppError("Calculation Failed")
        # or just change the message (and probably not print anything)
        # raise ValueError("List must contain nine numbers.")
        # or fix the problem
        # num_array = my_default_array


    mean_list.append(np.mean(num_array, axis=0).tolist())
    mean_list.append(np.mean(num_array, axis=1).tolist())
    mean_list.append(np.mean(num_array).tolist())
```

You have multiple options after catching an exception. Maybe the problem can be fixed and the program can continue. Maybe you want to convert the exception to another exception type. Maybe you want to convert that exception into an error return value. By default, python assumes that you just want to continue execution at the end of the try/except block.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. The raise worked. Appreciate it. Answer ticked up.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `return` to exit the function once `except` block is compiled

```py
import numpy as np

def calculate(num_list):
    try:
        num_array = np.array(num_list)
        num_array = np.reshape(num_array, (3, 3))
        # If the number of elements in num_list
        # is less than 9, np.reshape will return a
        # ValueError

    except ValueError:
        print("List must contain nine numbers.")
        return

    # The problem is that after catching error with  
    # except ValueError:, the function continues 
    # and runs the three lines below.
    # And so, since num_array is not a valid input, I get
    # an axis value error.

    mean_list.append(np.mean(num_array, axis=0).tolist())
    mean_list.append(np.mean(num_array, axis=1).tolist())
    mean_list.append(np.mean(num_array).tolist())
```

Comment: Many thanks. Adding return diid it. I'm rqual parts thankful and embarassed. thanks for yout patience.

Comment: Sorry abouit that. I thought I already did. must have clicked it twice. But it's ticked up now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you can use exit() after the print statement to exit out of the program if an exception occurs.